# I'm Getting this error EXPECTED IDENTIFIER. I cant understand the error. I have attached the code and the error below

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner

    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("player 1 wins!\n");
    }
    else if (score2 > score1)
    {
        printf("player 2 wins!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Tie \n");
    }



int compute_score(string word)
{
    int score = 0;
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    for(int i = 0, len = strlen(word); i < len; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word[i]))
        {
            score += POINTS(word[i] - 'A');
        }
        else if (islower(word[i]))
        {
            score += POINTS(word[i] - 'a');
        }
    }
    return score;
}
}
```

---

```
playground/ $ make playground
playground.c:28:4: error: expected identifier or '('
   if (score1 > score2)
   ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors were generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: playground] Error 1
```

---

Comment: You can't have a function inside of a function and `compute_score` is inside `main`.

Comment: Also: `POINTS(word[i] - 'A');` use square brackets to access array values. `POINTS[word[i] - 'A'];`

Comment: AFAICT, the code shown doesn't match the reported error message.  The line number seems to be wrong.  Please make sure the code and the error message match exactly.

Comment: The code seems OK in the line that is reported. (The errors mentioned above still apply). Maybe you compiled without saving latest version of your source code?